# Capture previous activity's details in Android library project

Tags: java, android

I need to know if I can retrieve the previous activity's name and package name inside the activity present in Android library project.

**Scenario:** Two projects: android project A and android library project B.

**Description -** Now, B is added as a library project of A. A is having several activities, from where It can jump to Activities of Project B.

**What i need ?** I need to capture the details of the Activity, from where the flow came into Library project.

Here, **I don't want to put any flag in the activities while passing an intent to start the Activity** of Library project.

If anyone is having a proper solution to this query, please respond.

Answer (score 1):

Without adding flags to an intent, it is impossible to find out the Activity that called the library Activity in your project.

As a workaround, instead of using startActivity(your_intent), you could do startActivityForResult(your_intent) and then use the method:

```
public ComponentName getCallingActivity();
```

This will achieve the same result for practical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `startActivityForResult`

If you start the activity with `startActivityForResult` then you can get calling activity by

```
getCallingActivity().getClassName()
```

or

```
ComponentName prev = this.getCallingActivity();
```

**Note -** If you will start the child activity as a normal was ie. using startActivity() then getCallingActivity() method will return null. This is mentioned in the below link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity()